# How many / how long are stashes saved by git?

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm very new to git and have some question about stashing. If I've worked on a branch but was not able to get to a position where I can commit the branch, stashing is the right thing to use. My questions regarding stashing are:

1. How many stashes are saved?
2. How long are these stashes saved?
3. Do they just temporarily save the work such that the changes are lost when you reboot your computer?

If someone could quickly help clarifying these would be really appreciated.

Comment: 1. As many as you create. 2. As long as you don't *drop*, *pop*, or *clear* them. 3. No; stashes will still be accessible after a reboot. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: Downvoter, the question may be more subtle than you think...

Comment: In git you are almost never in a position where you can't commit.  I don't personally find stash to be all that useful.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> **1 - How many stashes are saved?**

Stashes don't appear out of thin air; only if you create them, using

```
git stash
```

or, equivalently,

```
git stash save
```

So how many are saved? As many as you create.

> **2 - How long are these stashes saved?**

This question looks innocent, but the answer is actually quite subtle. There are two aspects to consider here: 1) the stash reflog, and 2) the repository's object database.

When you create a stash, Git

- adds an entry to the stash reflog,
- creates two (three if you use the `--include-untracked` flag) commit objects in the repository's database: one that corresponds to the WIP (work in progress) in your working tree, and another that corresponds to the state of your staging area (a.k.a. index).

Edit: those commit objects are bona fide commits, as can be verified by running `git cat-file -t` on them. They just happen to not be reachable from any branch; see [torek's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190837/how-many-how-long-are-stashes-saved-by-git/26192691?noredirect=1#comment47117752_26192691).

By default, Git's garbage collection will automatically delete reflog entries that are older than 90 days; you can specify a different "lifetime" for stash reflog entries, by running

```
git config gc.refs/stash.reflogexpire <lifetime>
```

However, [as torek notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190837/how-many-how-long-are-stashes-saved-by-git#comment47121255_26192691), Git handles stashes specially – even though old reflog entries are normally deleted automatically, Git will never delete reflog entries for `refs/stash` unless you explicitly tell it to.

In other words, Git will not delete stashes on its own; a stash will remain in your local repository as long as you don't voluntarily

- *drop* it, using

  ```
  git stash drop <stash-reference>
  ```

  which deletes the specified stash entry from the stash reflog;
- *pop* it, using

  ```
  git stash pop <stash-reference>
  ```

  which applies the specified stash and then deletes the corresponding entry from the stash reflog; or
- run

  ```
  git stash clear
  ```

which deletes *all* entries of the stash reflog (be careful with that one).

However, be aware that those three actions only affect the stash reflog. In particular, they do not immediately cause the associated "WIP" and "index" objects to be deleted from your repository's database; they merely make those objects unreachable. The latter will remain in "repository limbo" for a while, until they eventually get garbage-collected and die a "true death".

That's a useful thing to know: if you accidentally *drop* a stash, you might still be able to retrieve it from the entrails of your repo, if you can remember or identify the SHAs of its two objects (WIP and index).

> **3 - Do they just temporarily save the work such that the changes are lost when you reboot your computer?**

No. Stashes are no different from any other commit objects; a reboot has no effect on them.

Comment: Side note: they're not just "commit-like objects", they are in fact commits: they're just commits that are on *no* branch.  I'd say "creates two commits" rather than "creates two commit-like objects".  And, the `stash` ref has a special unusual default expiry time of "never".

Comment: @torek I had to double check with `git cat-file -t` but you're right about those objects being commits. However, where in the doc is it mentioned that the `stash` ref doesn't expire?

Comment: It's documented poorly-at-best, perhaps not at all other than in the release notes.  In `builtin/reflog.c` is this bit, though: `if (!strcmp(ref, "refs/stash")) {` with code to set the expiry to "never", and the comment: "If unconfigured, make stash never expire".  It's not entirely clear to me what the additional code (not shown here) inside that `if` is testing, though, before it sets the expiry to "never".

Comment: @torek That's a great find. Here's a [link](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a269e52a5d0c82567c5b39cc194cc90f9fa9156/builtin/reflog.c#L497-L506) to the actual lines of code you're referring to on Github.

Comment: @torek The other lines are checking whether the user explicitly passed the following flags: `[--expire=<time>] [--expire-unreachable=<time>]`.  If they didn't pass one of these flags, it's setting to zero (i.e. never). Otherwise the flags passed are applied and the defaults don't apply.  You'll see similar logic directly below for the other reflogs (instead of setting to zero, it sets to the default of course).

Comment: I know this is an old question, but what about unreachable stashes, will they be deleted if I run `git gc`? For example: I stash on a branch A, I switch branches, and I delete branch A → the stash may now be unreachable. Will it still be kept in tact after a `git gc --agressive`?

Answer (score 3):

Git stashes are saved until your hard disk dies (unlike commits, which are usually transmitted to some other computer via `git push` so will outlive a hard disk failure).

You can have as many stashes as you want.  Get rid of old ones when you feel  like it by running `git stash drop` or `git stash clear` (read the docs for those).