# Undo git reset --hard after git stash pop

Tags: git, git-stash, git-reset

I had some changes in the stash that I attempted to recover using `git stash pop`. There were some merge conflicts, and rather than resolving them, I decided to just reset it. Unfortunately, in a moment of stupidity, I did a `git reset --hard`, and now all of the previously stashed changes are gone.

Is there any way to recover these changes? I've tried `git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable  HEAD`, but none of the commit hashes listed refer to the changes I need. What else can I do? or did I just lose all of that work?

Comment: Your stash isn't lost forever; it still lives in Git's object database... at least for a time. You might still be able to retrieve it. See the end of item 2 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190837/how-many-how-long-are-stashes-saved-by-git/26192691#26192691

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just after posting this, I thought to check .git/refs/stash, which I thought would be blank after the pop. However, likely due to the merge conflict, it still had the hash from the stash I had tried to pop!

I did a `git stash apply` with the hash and a `git reset` to resolve the merge conflicts the lazy way.

Sorry if this was a git-noob question and answer. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Also, in case your stash is no longer in the list (you did `git stash drop` etc.) you can still recover it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/91795/4231110

Answer (score 2):

`git help stash` :

> Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand and call git stash drop manually afterwards.

so the stash you though has gone is still in your stash list, just `git stash list` to find it.