# Does GIT STASH persist even after a computer shutdown?

Tags: linux, git, github

I've read about using git stash to save work on a particular branch when needing to work on another, but my question is do those saved changes only stay saved for a particular session, or would they remain saved until they are destroyed (even after rebooting a computer) and be recovered later?

The root of the problem is:
I have a computer with me at work which I develop on, and which cannot access the internet. Thus, I cannot push changes to git remotely. I would need to save them temporarily, shut down my computer, and push them when I get home. Is this possible?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190837/how-many-how-long-are-stashes-saved-by-git

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the stash is persisted to disk, and thus survives reboot.

`git` doesn't retain **any** content in-memory (or in an alternate fragile state, such as unlinked files) between command invocations; doing so would require an out-of-process daemon or other component that isn't presently included -- thus, substantial extra complexity for no significant gain.

---

That said, given the workflow you've described, I don't see why you'd need to use the stash day-to-day when working disconnected. Just commit your changes locally, and `push` (**without** using `--force`) when connected. Depending on your team's workflow, it may be appropriate to rebase onto the current state of the branch, or to merge down new changes before pushing. Ask your team's dev lead which approach they prefer, if explicit workflow documentation local to your company or project isn't available.